# Easy way to back up MacBook running 10.5.8

Tags: backup

What's an easy way to back up the files on a Macbook that is running OS 10.5.8  ?

As far as I can see, I think iCloud only works with 10.7.2 and above, and MobileMe are not accepting new accounts...

Comment: If you have your own hard drive, I think Time Capsule works with that version (not 100% sure though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: Crashplan, it is free backup software if you backup to an external hard drive, if you backup to the cloud then it costs $$$ (not alot). the free backup only backups once a day, but it really does a great job. you just need to select the needed files and the location and the software backups everything automatically without to worry, it sends you emails if backup doesn't work for several days.

http://www.crashplan.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external hard drive that is at least as large as your computer’s hard drive, you can use [Time Machine](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#timemachine). Time Machine comes with Mac OS X 10.5.

If you need to make whole-disk backups, check out [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html).